# Running DOS command or batch file in tcl script in Windows 7 with ActiveTcl 8.5

Tags: windows, exec, dos, tcl

## The following is the tcl code.

```
#!/bin/sh
# \
exec tclsh "$0"  ${1+"$@"}

package require Expect
package require log
source [file join [info library] init.tcl]

set exp::winnt_debug 1

log::lvChannel debug stdout
log::log debug "debug msg ON\r"

set env(TERM) dumb

array set OPTS {
host    ""
user    ""
passwd  ""
login   telnet
prompt  "(%|#|>|\\$) $"
ls      "/bin/ls -A1"
}

set xlpad "yahoo.com"

exec [auto_execok dir]

while {1} {
spawn ping  $xlpad
set loss 0
set replya 0
for { set pingc 0 } { $pingc < 3 } { incr pingc 1} {
    expect { 
        "timed out" {
            incr loss 1
            puts "intercepted time out message: $loss\n"
        }
        "Reply" {
            incr replya 1
        }    
    }
    if { $replya > 2 } {    
        break               
    }
   }            
break
}

return
```

---

I got the following messages:

```
couldn't execute "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe \c dir": no such file or directory
    while executing
"exec [auto_execok dir]"
    (file "mytst.tcl" line 35)
```

But the ping works ok.

Comment: That needs to be /c.  Forward slash, not backward slash.  Good luck finding that bug.  Good thing it's open source though.

Answer (score 7):

`auto_execok` returns a list, which is passed to `exec` as a single argument. You need to expand the list:

```
exec {*}[auto_execok dir]
```

example:

```
% file mkdir tmp
% cd tmp
% close [open test w]
% exec [auto_execok dir]
couldn't execute "C:\WINNT\system32\cmd.exe \c dir": no such file or directory
% exec {*}[auto_execok dir]
 Volume in drive D is Data
 Volume Serial Number is ....

 Directory of d:\glennj\tmp

2011-09-30  10:08 AM    <DIR>          .
2011-09-30  10:08 AM    <DIR>          ..
2011-09-30  10:08 AM                 0 test
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  77,613,654,016 bytes free
```

Comment: I would have, but I was writing on my touchpad with no access to a Win box.

Comment: % exec {*} [auto_execok dir]
couldn't execute "*": no such file or directory  - How do I check if the ActivestateTcl was installed correctly ?  Thanks

Comment: @action, No space bewteen the `}` and the `[`! [Documentation is here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M9)

Comment: @glenn Thanks. A simple DOS batch file: 'cd c:\; dir;'  In tclsh, the batch file runs successfully.  In tcl script, '#!/bin/sh
# \
exec tclsh "$0"  ${1+"$@"}
set env(TERM) dumb


exec {*}[auto_execok dir]
exec mytst.bat
return

Comment: ' 
c:\tclsh mytst.tcl
couldn't execute "mytst.bat": no such file or directory
    while executing
"exec mytst.bat"
    (file "mytst.tcl" line 6)
Line 5 was neither executed nor displayed on stdout.

Comment: I don't have access to DOS at the moment, but try `exec {*}[auto_execok start "" mytst.bat]`

Comment: c:\>tclsh mytst.tcl
wrong # args: should be "auto_execok name"
    while executing
"auto_execok start "" mytst.bat"
    invoked from within
"exec {*}[auto_execok start "" mytst.bat]"
    (file "mytst.tcl" line 6)
C:\>           No luck with the try!

Comment: @action, right, my error: `exec {*}[auto_execok start] "" mytst.bat`

Comment: @glenn ... Thanks for the patience.  I'm getting closer. zz denotes new line.'
C:\work\config>REM Parameters that could be passed: -debug, -noad, -badgeip IP , -localip IP. 

zz C:\work\config>REM

zz C:\work\config>C:\jre\bin\java -classpath lib\config.jar config.vch.Vconfig -badgeip 10.213.213.213

zz XYZ 4.1.2012: Vconfig

zz Connecting to 10.213.213.213 at port: 5556
zz >
'The script starts the java session but expect couldn't continue.
The java code interacts with an embedded linux.  It seems that exec
is not the correct launch calling java script.  What would work ?

Comment: Well, if this is expect, then you would use `spawn`

Comment: @glenn, '
spawn [exec {*}[auto_execok start] "" vch.bat -badgeip 10.213.213.213] zz
expect "5556" zz
expect ">" zz
'  The following is the DOS output: '
C:\work\config>REM Parameters that could be passed: -debug, -noad, -badgeip IP , -localip IP zz

C:\work\config>REM zz

C:\work\config>C:\jre\bin\java -classpath lib\config.jar config.vch.Vconfig -badgeip 10.213.213.213 zz

XYZ 4.1.2012: Vconfig zz

Connecting to 10.213.213.213 at port: 5556 zz
> zz
'  The script spawns & starts the java session but expect couldn't receive the output text.  

'

Comment: Anyone can help me getting spawn to call java batch file ?